# Using XPATH to find a li based on text contains doesnt work on text after a <b> tag

Tags: html, xpath

So I've got some li on a page and I'm trying to identify it with some XPATH, only trouble is I need to make sure that all the text matches so I need to identify on all the text and there is a  in there that is giving me hassle (I'm using a chrome addin to validate the XPATH and it keeps telling me its null when I try), any suggestions welcome!

Here is the html on the page: -

```
<li>
    Some pre text, <b>bold</b> nothing here is identified.
</li>
```

Here is what I've tried that doesnt work: -

```
//ul/li[contains(text(),'') and contains(text(),'bold') and contains(text(),'nothing here is identified')]
```

I also tried this just to see if it works (bear in mind my XPATH needs to check all the text within that li), but it won't identify it at all using any text after the bold tags...

```
//ul/li[contains(text(),'nothing here is identified')]
```

What obvious XPATH trickery and I missing...?

Cheers

Comment: Does replacing `text()` by just `.` work? Because, `text()` would give you multiple text nodes, and `contains()` wouldn't allow that.

Comment: Oddly enough yes works like a charm, feel free to make this a suggestion and I'll mark it as the answer.  However, any insights as to why this is would be great as I have no idea! :)

Comment: Cheers, wasn't aware that contains doesn't cope with multiple text nodes being returned, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
//ul/li[contains(.,'') and contains(.,'bold') and contains(.,'nothing here is identified')]
```

Use of `text()` would give you three text nodes, as there are 3 nodes infact, which when used in `contains()` will be an irrecoverable error:

1. `Some pre text,`
2. `bold`
3. `nothing here is identified.`

But the use of `.` or `current()`(both mean the same here), would give you only one string(concatenation of all three nodes mentioned above).